# How do i make the div blocks responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following code that lists 5 steps in a row on large screen devices like laptops and desktops and would like to make the same code responsive for mobile and tablets but for the past 3 days i can't get it to work.

I have tried media queries and they don't seem to do the trick. How can I alter the code to make it responsive?

```css
.row-equal-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.p_column {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 5px 15px 0;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
}
.p_column:first-child {
    background: #c81f56;
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #c81f56;
}
/*Code for arrow*/

.p_column:before,
.p_column:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 42%;
    bottom: 86px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Stroke */

.p_column:before {
    right: -30px;
    border-left-color: #d4d4d4;
    border-width: 15px;
}
/* Fill */

.p_column:after {
    right: -29px;
    border-left-color: #fff;
    border-width: 15px;
}
.p_column p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0
}
.p_column:first-child:before {
    border-left-color: #c81f56;
}
.p_column:first-child:after {
    border-left-color: #c81f56;
}
.p_column:last-child:before,
.p_column:last-child:after {
    display: none
}
/*color change hover*/

.p_column:hover {
    background: #b0b9c1;
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #b0b9c1;
}
.p_column:hover:before {
    border-left-color: #b0b9c1;
}
.p_column:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #b0b9c1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 424px) {
 .steps-responsive: max-width: 100% !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 425px) and (max-width: 768px){
  .steps-responsive: max-width: 50% !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
 .steps-responsive: max-width: 16.66% !important;
}
```

```html
      <div class="row" >
         <div class="row-equal-height" >
            <div class="p_column text-center">
               <div class="border-4 border-gray-400 rounded-full w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold">
                  1
               </div>
     <h4>
                  Dial Short-code.
               </h4><br/>
               <p>
                  Dial *389*0# on your mobile phone
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class=" p_column text-center ">
               <div class="border-4 border-gray-400 rounded-full w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold">
                  2
               </div>
               <h4>
                  Enter MOMO Card Number.
               </h4><br/>
               <p> 
                  Enter the 16 digits number on the card 
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class=" p_column text-center ">
               <div class="border-4 border-gray-400 rounded-full w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold">
                  3
               </div>
               <h4>
                  Enter Personal Information.
               </h4><br/>
               <p> 
                  Enter your first name..
               </p>
            </div>
    <div class=" p_column text-center ">
               <div class="border-4 border-gray-400 rounded-full w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold">
                  4
               </div>
               <h4>
                  Key in Security Pin.
               </h4><br/>
               <p> 
                  Key in your preferred four-digit PIN and confirm the same PIN.
               </p>
            </div>
    <div class=" p_column text-center ">
               <div class="border-4 border-gray-400 rounded-full w-16 h-16 flex justify-center items-center text-2xl font-bold">
                  5
               </div>
               <h4>
                  SMS Confirmation.
               </h4><br/>
               <p> 
                  An SMS message is received indicating card will be active within 48hrs.
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I want the blocks to remain 5 in a line on wide screens, 2 per row on medium screens (tablets held in horizontal mode) and 1 per row on small screen devices.

Comment: Consider using frameworks like Bootstrap - makes your life much easier.

Comment: did you added the `meta` tag for media queries?
Also, you media queries are bad formatted. You need to include { ... } after the class, not : just like you would do with normal css

Comment: For truly responsive design, you should consider replacing all your absolute units (e.g. "px") with relative units (e.g. "%" and "em").

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks for the tip. I will surely consider that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this code on your css for responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .row-equal-height {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .p_column {
        width: 25%;
        margin: 5px 2% 0;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .p_column {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @siddhant I have no idea why i didnt pay attention to my css and media querries. I learnt some new css as well. This really worked for me and solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @Selase